# How do I express this vector field, given "in terms of $\mathbb{C}$", in the standard notation for derivations?

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

In a set of lecture notes (not available online) that I'm currently working through, one is given the following set-up:

> Consider rotational vector fields on the plane
>       $\mathbb{R}^{2}\cong\mathbb{C}$ with coordinates $(x,y)\cong
>     z=x+\imath y$.  Let $X$ be the vector field given by $X(z)=\imath
>     z=-y+\imath x\in\mathbb{C}\cong T_{z}\mathbb{C}$, i.e. 
>       $X(x,y)=-y\partial_{x}+x\partial_{y}$.

This is all fine by me, but there is one thing that I don't understand: How do I express $X(z)$ in terms of the standard notation for tangent vectors (i.e. I'm looking for the *complex* equivalent of $X(x,y)=-y\partial_x+x\partial_y$). There are two approaches that seem sensible, but they give irreconcilable results---at least so it seems:

1. Use $z=x+\imath y$ and $\partial_z=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_x-\imath\partial_y)$ and directly "translate" the expression in real coordinates. This yields **[algebra corrected in edit]**
   $$X(z)=\imath\frac{z-\bar z}{2}(\partial_z+\partial_{\bar z})
   +\imath\frac{z+\bar z}{2}(\partial_z-\partial_{\bar z})
   =\imath (z\partial_z -\bar z\partial_{\bar z}) $$
2. Assume that the isomorphism $\mathbb C\cong T_z\mathbb C $ identifies $X(z)\in \mathbb{C}$ with $X(z)\partial_z+0\cdot\partial_{\bar z}$ so that we obtain 
   $$ X(z)=\imath z \partial_z $$
   But when "translating back" to real variables one then obtains
   $$ X(z)=\frac{1}{2}\imath(x+\imath y)(\partial_x-\imath \partial_y)
   =\frac{1}{2}\Big((\imath x-y)\partial_x+(x+\imath y)\partial_y\Big)$$

At first sight, it seems reasonable to simply say that the second method is based on a wrong assumption, and to simply dismiss it (even though I don't know *why* it's wrong). However, continuing in the lecture notes I find

> Its trajectories are given
>       by $c_{z}(t)=e^{\imath t}z$.  Indeed, $\dot{c}_{z}(t)=\imath
>     e^{\imath t}z=\imath c_{z}(t)$.

Assuming the first approach is correct we indeed obtain something different: It seems like the "translation" to the tangent space notation was not only useless (since the solution simply seems to solve the equation $c'(t)=\imath c$ with initial condition $c(0)=z$) but leads to the wrong solution! Of course, the *second* approach here does give the correct result... My question is therefore twofold:

What does the vector field $X$ correspond to in terms of the notation for derivations of smooth functions on $\mathbb C$, and is this at all relevant for finding its integral curves (trajectories)? If the answer to the latter is "no", please elaborate!

**EDIT**: After correcting some elementary mistakes pointed out in the answers, some of the confusion is resolved, but part of the question still stands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it should be pointed out that the literature is full with *different* definitions and *different* relations between real tangent vectors and complex tangent vectors. Having said that, let us try to understand the situation you are in.

The *real tangent space* at a point, is the real $2$-dimensional space spanned by the vectors $\partial_x$ and $\partial_y$. The *complex tangent space* is the complexification of the real tangent space. Namely, it is the complex $2$-dimensional space spanned by $\partial_x$ and $\partial_y$. However, when working with complex tangent vectors, it is more common to use the two independent vectors $\partial_z$ and $\partial_{\overline{z}}$ as a basis. The translation formula is$$\partial_z=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_x-i\partial_y),\quad\partial_{\overline{z}}=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_x+i\partial_y),$$or alternatively,$$\partial_x=\partial_z+\partial_{\overline{z}},\quad\partial_y=i(\partial_z-\partial_{\overline{z}}).$$Hence, for the vector field in question we have$$X=-y\partial_x+x\partial_y=-y(\partial_z+\partial_{\overline{z}})+ix(\partial_z-\partial_{\overline{z}})=iz\partial_z+\overline{iz}\partial_{\overline{z}}.$$

However, there is another tangent space in the picture, and this is the *holomorphic* tangent space, which is the complex $1$-dimensional space spanned by $\partial_z$. It comes with a projection from the complex tangent space to the holomorphic tangent space, given by$$\partial_z\mapsto\partial_z,\quad\partial_{\overline{z}}\mapsto0.$$This projection, when restricted to the real tangent space, yields an *isomorphism of real vector spaces* from the real tangent space to the holomorphic one, given by$$\partial_x\mapsto\partial_z,\quad\partial_y\mapsto i\partial_z.$$It is customary to identify the real and holomorphic spaces via the above isomorphism. Doing so, our vector field is expressed as$$X=iz\partial_z.$$

As for trajectories, we should notice first that it is a different world to begin with. We are looking for a curve $c:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$, and this involves no complex derivatives, since the domain of the curve is *real*, not complex. Hence, I'd say the answer to your second question is no. The way to find the trajectories is exactly as written in your post.

Answer (score 1):

Comments to the question (v2):

1. There seems to be a factor half missing from some of OP's formulas. Note that $$z~=~x+iy\quad\text{and}\quad\bar{z}~=~x-iy$$ yield via the chain rule
   $$ \partial_z~=~\frac{1}{2}\left(\partial_x-i\partial_y \right)\quad\text{and}\quad\partial_{\bar{z}}~=~\frac{1}{2}\left(\partial_x+i\partial_y \right).$$
2. Note that in polar coordinates $z=re^{i\theta}$, the vector field becomes
   $$ X~=~-y\partial_x+x\partial_y~=~\partial_{\theta}.$$
3. Using the chain rule, the vector field becomes
   $$ X~=~i\left(z\partial_z-\bar{z}\partial_{\bar{z}}\right). $$